# Azure funtion app integration with vnet not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

I have created an Azure function app in the premium tier and used the Vnet integration to be able to access app services in the vnet. Also, I have another app function that is connected to my vnet via a private endpoint.

My problem is that when I add the proxy to the vnet integrated function and run it I face error 500 and the request doesn't even reach the app function inside the vnet. Is there any solution for this ?

[image: This is my subnets]

[image]

IP 10.10.1.6 is the one that is connected to my private endpoint and I'm trying to send request to it through proxies:
[image]

but whenever I copy the Proxy URL I get this error [image]

Comment: Could you please describe your question more clearly such as how do you configure the vnet integrated with function 1 and 2 or app services, and how do you configure the private endpoint for which function app? How many vnets or subnets? how do you configure the proxy backend? It might be helpful if you could provide more screenshots or network descriptions?

Comment: edited the post hope I am more clear now

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is a HTTP 500 internal server error.

So the request is getting to the app service, but the code in the app service is failing.

To check what is failing you can use Application Insights.

Comment: The problem was that in the proxy i should have used the the app service URL itself instead of the ip address